# Why cannot I set up a VS Code development environment with Vagrant?

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set up a vscode development environment using Vagrant.

My host OS is Windows 7 and my guest OS, Ubuntu.

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: 'bootstrap.sh', keep_color: true
end
```

And this the script I'm running for bootstraping

```
apt-get update

echo "Installing build tools"
apt-get install -y build-essential
apt-get install -y make g++ git curl vim python python-software-properties
apt-get install -y libsecret-1-dev libx11-dev libxkbfile-dev

echo "Installing NodeJS"
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
apt-get install nodejs

echo "Configure npm folder"
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
source ~/.profile

# Install gulp-cli
npm install gulp-cli -g

echo "Clone vscode"
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vscode
cd vscode
./scripts/npm.sh install --unsafe-perm --arch=x64

gulp vscode-win32-x64 --max_old_space_size=4096
```

Doing this, **I'm not getting the devDependencies installed**.

Could someone helping me to fix this? I think it would be nice for the vscode community to have a running Vagrant environment for development.

Comment: have you tried to replace `npm.sh install --unsafe-perm --arch=x64` by adding `--only=dev` ?

Comment: No, ti's not working neither.